# How to prevent Windows 10 from going to S3 Sleep when Sleep is disabled?

Tags: windows-10, sleep

My Windows 10 Pro version is 1703, build 15063.540.

Settings -> System -> Batery -> Power & sleep:

[image: Settings -> System -> Batery -> Power & sleep]

Is obviously set to Never.

In spite of this setting, my legal copy of Windows 10 Pro goes into suspend in a few moments, maybe a minute, since first gone to suspend manually, I mean:

Start -> Power -> Sleep.

Until I do this first sleep, everything works normally, i.e. the laptop stays always on. I have no idea why or what causes the issue, but I would very much like to start debugging this thing, since I would like to use sleep mode.

Where shall I start?

What do you need me to provide?

Please do comment, if there is no obvious answer.

**powercfg -availablesleepstates**

```
PS C:\> powercfg -availablesleepstates
```

> The following sleep states are available on this system:

```
Standby (S3)
Hibernate
Hybrid Sleep
Fast Startup
```

> The following sleep states are not available on this system:

```
Standby (S1)
    The system firmware does not support this standby state.

Standby (S2)
    The system firmware does not support this standby state.

Standby (S0 Low Power Idle)
    The system firmware does not support this standby state.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, Run prompt will appear.
2. Type `regedit` and press OK button; confirm the UAC prompt.
3. In the header of Registry Editor put this path:

   ```
   Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0
   ```
4. Double-click on Attributes value and change its value to 2.
5. Close the Registry editor and open Control Panel.
6. In the Control Panel navigate to this path:

   > Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Power Options -> Change Plan Settings
7. Click on Change advanced power settings.
8. Navigate to item **System unattended sleep timeout** and expand it.
9. Change its value to your liking, e.g. 1 day is 1440 minutes.

Source: [Microsoft Answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-keeps-going-into-sleep-after-1-minute/787e8cea-32ce-4ea0-a281-13c32a75352d?auth=1)

Comment: Works for Windows 8.1 too

Comment: I would like this better if there were some explanation behind the registry setting. Is this changing something internally unavailable in the GUI? Is there an equivalent `powercfg.exe /setacvalueindex ...` command that would accomplish the same thing (and be slightly less cryptic)?